# Making Toad not stay with Mario on Screen

Tags: java

I am working on a Mario game. So far, I have made the code for the background, the movement(including gravity), and have inserted one toad at the beginning of the level. The frame repeats itself in a never-ending loop, and unfortunately, when you run the program, the toad image stays with the Mario character as the Mario moves (as the Mario is moving right, the Toad tails him). I would like it to be that the Toad is left behind when the Mario leaves the screen; just as in real Mario games where if you choose not to kill the Goomba, the Goomba isn't on the screen after you move right enough. How can I do this?

Here is some of my code

```
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Toads {
    int x, y, nx, nx2, distanceTraveled;
    Image i;
    ImageIcon redToad = new ImageIcon("images/toad2.png");

    public Toads() {
        i = redToad.getImage();                                                       //Give the player the image
        x = 190;                                                                                  //The original x position of the player
       y = 273;                                                                             //The original y position of the player
       nx = -0;                                                                             //Repeating background 1
       nx2 = -575;                                                                          //Repeating background 2
      distanceTraveled = 24;
}
public Image getImage() {return i;}
  import java.awt.*;                                                                           
   import java.awt.event.*;                                                                         

import javax.swing.*;

public class board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
        player p;                                                                                
        Image background, menuBg;                                                                
        Timer time;                                                                              
    private menu Menu;
    private frame Frame;
    private Toads toad;

    public static enum STATE {MENU,HELP,GAME};

    public static STATE State = STATE.MENU;

    public board() {
            this.addMouseListener(new mouseInput());
            p = new player();                                                                    
            Menu = new menu();
            toad = new Toads();
            addKeyListener(new AL());                                                            //Listen for keys
            setFocusable(true);                                                                                                                  //Allows movement         
            ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("images/MarioMenu.jpg");                  //Image for menu
            menuBg = i.getImage();
            i = new ImageIcon("images/Mario_Background.png");  //Image for background
            background = i.getImage();                                                           //Give the background the image
            time = new Timer(20,this);                                                           //Timer set to update "this" class every 20 milliseconds(Approximately 50fps)
            time.start();                                                                        //Actually start the timer
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            p.move();                                                                            //Call the move method from the player class
            repaint();                                                                           //Repaint
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {                                                 //Graphics method
            if(State==STATE.GAME) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;                                             //casts 2d graphics(or however you would explain it)

                            g2d.drawImage(background, -p.nx, 0, null);                                   //Draw the background image
                            g2d.drawImage(background, -p.nx2, 0, null);                                  //Draw the background image

                            if(-p.nx<-575)                                                              //If going forwards
                                    p.nx=-575;                                                              //Start placing forwards every 575px in front on the last one
                            else if(-p.nx>575)                                                          //If going backwards
                                    p.nx=575;                                                               //Start placing backwards every 575px behind the last one

                            if(-p.nx2<-575)                                                             //If going forwards
                                    p.nx2=-575;                                                             //Start placing forwards every 575px in front on the last one
                            else if(-p.nx2>575)                                                         //If going backwards
                                    p.nx2=575;                                                              //Start placing backgrounds every 575px behind the last one

                            g2d.drawImage(p.getImage(), p.getX(), p.getY(), null);                      //Draw the player at the position he is currently(Coordinate values taken from player class)
                            g2d.drawImage(toad.getImage(), toad.x, toad.y, null);
            } 
            else if (State == STATE.HELP){

            }
            else {
                    g.drawImage(menuBg, 0, 0, null);
                    Menu.render(g);
            }
    }

    private class AL extends KeyAdapter {                                                    //Action Listener extends key adapter
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {                                                 //On key press
                    p.keyPressed(e);                                                                 //Send whatever key was pressed  TO the keyPressed  method in the player class
            }
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {                                                //On key release
                    p.keyReleased(e);                                                                //Send whatever key was released TO the keyReleased method in the player class
            }
    }
```

}

Basically, I am stuck on finding a way to make the frame work like a Mario game- for example, if the entire level is 3000 pixels by 3000 pixels, how would you make it so that the screen is (say) 500 pixels by 500 pixels and moves with Mario(and other objects on other "screens" don't move with Mario)?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable called screenX and screenY, which are the coordinates of the upper left of the screen render to the player, relative to the upper left corner of the entire world. When rendering, first check if an object is on the screen by preforming a simple rectangular collision check. If it is on the screen, render it at `(actualX - screenX, actualY - screenY)`. That should do exactly what you need.